# Difference between of "K extends keyof T" vs. directly using "keyof T"?

Tags: typescript

Is there any difference between the following typescript definitions:

```
function prop<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

and

```
function prop2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

I mean no, but maybe I have overseen something. Are there any benefits to use the first version (which is often used in the docs)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case the return type will be `T[K]` while in the second case it will be `T[keyof T]`. `K` can at it's widest be `keyof T` but it can be a specific string literal type representing a key. This means if `K` is a specific property the return value will be of the same type as the property:

```
function prop<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}
function prop2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}

let o = {
    p1: 0,
    p2: ''
}

let v = prop(o, 'p1') // is number, K is of type 'p1'
let v2 = prop2(o, 'p1') // is number | string, no extra info is captured
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: I understand the difference now. But when would the behavior exhibited by `prop2` ever be desirable or useful? In other words, why doesn't TypeScript, as a design decision, make `keyof T` produce the behavior exhibited by `extends keyof T` and eliminate this confusion?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great difference between these 2 expression, which will cause the compiler to behave differently.

---

```js
function prop<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

This help [constraint the generic parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to avoid using `any` but also ensure input param is prop of `T`

---

```js
function prop2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

This does not throw compiler error for getter but will throw in setter case:
`Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`

```js
function prop2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T, value: any) {
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

The reason is `keyof` will cause obj[key] to have `never` type (no overlap of keys), read more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758818/9814737