# TypeScript generic function param and return type inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What's the difference between these two function definitions?

With first `getProperty`, TypeScript can infer the **return** type. But the second one fails.

```js
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}

function getProperty2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    name: 'test',
}

const name2 = getProperty(obj, 'name');
name2.length;   // This is OK, name2 is infered as string

const name3 = getProperty2(obj, 'name');
name3.length;  // This is ERROR! name3 is of type string | number
```

Comment: duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099089/difference-between-of-k-extends-keyof-t-vs-directly-using-keyof-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099089/difference-between-of-k-extends-keyof-t-vs-directly-using-keyof-t)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between of "K extends keyof T" vs. directly using "keyof T"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099089/difference-between-of-k-extends-keyof-t-vs-directly-using-keyof-t)

Answer (score 2):

On the first one, `K` is explicitly defined. So, when you pass `name`, Typescript can infer the type. However on the second one, `getProperty2` function expects any `keyof` `T`. So, the return type becomes `string | number` (if you add more key to `obj`, this will become more complex). That's why Typescript is not sure which one will you get.

You can fix this by using `as` as follows since you are sure that you will get a `string` in return.

```js
const name3 = getProperty2(obj, 'name') as string;
name3.length;
```

Comment: But how can TypeScript infer the **return** type of `getProperty`? I find TypeScript official doc, they have explicitly define the **return** type, see this link [TypeScript official index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), and their code is `function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] { return o[propertyName];}`

Comment: They didn't need to define return type as well. You can ![check this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kttccd?file=index.ts)

Typescript can do that because you pass the name of the key. From that point, `K` becomes `string`