# Type ... is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)

Tags: typescript

The following code snippet reports an error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)` in the line `obj[prop] = value` and I struggle understanding why?

```
interface fooType {
    s: string,
    n: number,
}

function bar(value: string, obj: fooType, prop: keyof fooType) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        obj[prop] = value;
    }
}

const foo = {s: '', n: 0};

bar('s', foo, 's');

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`prop: keyof fooType` means that prop could be `"s"` or `"n"`. But those two property values have incompatible types. So typescript tries to infer a value that could be assignable to both by finding the intersection of the types of the properties `.s` *and* `.n`. So it does: `string & number`, which have no overlap, so the type is `never`.

If you want to type an argument as a union (like `"s" | "n"`) *and* you need to know which member of that union it is, then you need generics.

For generic parameters you need at least two here. One for the property name (we'll use `K` for key) you wish to update, and one for the value to make sure the it matches the property's type (we'll use `V` for value).

You can now drop the `typeof value === 'string'` because typescript will ensure the value is the right type for the property.

```
function bar<
    K extends keyof fooType,
    V extends fooType[K]
>(
    value: V,
    obj: fooType,
    prop: K
) {
    obj[prop] = value;
}

const foo = {s: '', n: 0};

bar('string', foo, 's'); // works
bar(123, foo, 'n'); // works


// Should be type errors:
bar('string', foo, 'n') // '"string"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
bar(123, foo, 's') // '123' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Comment: This has been catching me out for *years*, even though I am pretty comfy with generics. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 6):

`fooType['s']` is type `string`, `fooType['n']` is type number, so `obj[prop]` is type `string & number` because it's the only type assignable to `obj[prop]`. And `string & number` = `never`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use generics here, then it can match the types correctly.

```js
interface fooType {
    s: string,
    n: number,
}

function bar<
  OBJ extends fooType,
  KEY extends keyof OBJ,
  VAL extends OBJ[KEY]
>(value: VAL, obj: OBJ, prop: KEY) {
  obj[prop] = value;
}

const foo = {s: '', n: 0};

bar('s', foo, 's');

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: What purpose does `VAL` being generic serve here?  That is, why is `value` not of type `OBJ[KEY]` instead of `VAL extends OBJ[KEY]`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback! Your solution works but I do not really understand why  need a template? What exactly is wrong with my original approach? Why is using `extends` in the template syntax needed?

Comment: because `prop` can be `n` and then string isn't assignable to it.