# Typescript compiler gives unclear error message when assigning a typed value

Tags: typescript

I get an unclear TS-Error. Sure this is an easy one, but it seems to have so many facets I don't know how to search for it properly. I kinda know it's related to "noImplicitAny" and "strictNullChecks" in TS-Config. Please don't only post a solution but shed some light on what this error is and what the compiler is trying to say.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface MyState {
  someKeyA: string[];
  someKeyB: Person | null;
  isOk: boolean;
}

const getInitialState = (): MyState => {
  return {
    someKeyA: ["This is a wonderful state", "But sth is not right"],
    someKeyB: {
      name: "Francis",
      age: 33
    },
    isOk: false
  };
};

class MyWonderFullClass {
  state: MyState;

  constructor() {
    this.state = getInitialState();
  }

  setSingleStateField = (
    fieldId: keyof MyState,
    value: MyState[keyof MyState]
  ) => {
    if (!fieldId || !value) {
      return;
    }

    this.state[fieldId] = value; 
    /*FAILS, giving: Type 'true | Person | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] & (Person | null) & boolean'. Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string[] & (Person | null) & boolean'.*/

  };
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-nijj9?file=/index.ts

Comment: Also foud this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337598/in-typescript-what-do-extends-keyof-and-in-keyof-mean

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758438/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-never-2322/61758818#61758818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that `value` is of the type corresponding to `fieldId`.

I solved it by extracting the key type:

```js
  setSingleStateField = <K extends keyof MyState>(
    fieldId: K,
    value: MyState[K]
  ) => {
    if (!fieldId || !value) {
      return;
    }

    this.state[fieldId] = value;
  };
```