# Get object value by dynamic key in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to export just 1 value of a config object depending on the `process.env.NODE_ENV` value, so I'm trying to get the value of the `configEnvs` variables like `configEnvs['local']` but I get an error trying to access one key of the object. I tried using an `enum` as a key to set it's possible values, but it didn't work.

I'm currently trying to get the key value using `getKeyValue` which gets the object and limits the key value to only the object's keys, but it then says that the `string` I'm trying to pass a key is not assignable to the possible options.

```
const getKeyValue = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key];

const { NODE_ENV, REACT_APP_ENV } = process.env;

interface IConfigEnv {
  DB_DNS: string;
}
interface IConfig {
  local: IConfigEnv;
  development: IConfigEnv;
  production: IConfigEnv;
}

let configEnvs: IConfig = {
  local: {
    DB_DNS: "https://localhost:4000",
  },

  development: {
    DB_DNS: "https://my-dev.web.com",
  },

  production: {
    DB_DNS: "https://api.web.com",
  },
};

const nodeEnv = REACT_APP_ENV || NODE_ENV || "development";
const config: IConfigEnv = getKeyValue(configEnvs, nodeEnv);

export default config;
```

I'm getting this error declaring `config`:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"development" | "production" | "local"'.`

Comment: The issue is that nobody stops the OS from stuffing a variable `NODE_ENV=99bottlesofbeer` into your program. You need to sanitize your variable in your code in such a way that it can _only_ have `development`, `production` or `local`. TypeScript is right to complain here!

Comment: Yeah, I know.. REACT_APP_ENV or NODE_ENV could be any `string`.  So, how can I ensure its value to one of `configEnvs` keys? Even if I loop and check, it still complains.

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099089/difference-between-of-k-extends-keyof-t-vs-directly-using-keyof-t

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using [Type Assertion](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion) like so:

```
export type NODE_ENVIRONMENTS = "local" | "development" | "production";

// Here using 'as' keyword
const NODE_ENV: NODE_ENVIRONMENTS = process.env.NODE_ENV as NODE_ENVIRONMENTS;
const REACT_APP_ENV: NODE_ENVIRONMENTS = process.env
  .REACT_APP_ENV as NODE_ENVIRONMENTS;

interface IConfigEnv {
  DB_DNS: string;
}

interface IConfigEnv {
  DB_DNS: string;
}
interface IConfig {
  local: IConfigEnv;
  development: IConfigEnv;
  production: IConfigEnv;
}

const config: IConfig = {
  local: {
    DB_DNS: "https://localhost:4000",
  },

  development: {
    DB_DNS: "https://api-dev.web.com",
  },

  production: {
    DB_DNS: "https://api.web.com",
  },
};

const nodeEnv: NODE_ENVIRONMENTS = REACT_APP_ENV || NODE_ENV || "development";

export default config[nodeEnv];
```

Answer (score 0):

A safer way to do this would be to use something like a [typeguard or type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) like so:

```
interface IConfigEnv {
  DB_DNS: string;
}
interface IConfig {
  local: IConfigEnv;
  development: IConfigEnv;
  production: IConfigEnv;
}

const acceptableEnvs = [ "local", "development", "production" ];
function assertEnv(k: any): asserts k is keyof IConfig {
  if (typeof k !== "string" || !acceptableEnvs.includes(k)) {
    throw new Error(
      `Environment must be one of '${acceptableEnvs.join("', '")}'. You passed '${k}'.`
    );
  }
}

const config: IConfig = {
  local: {
    DB_DNS: "https://localhost:4000",
  },

  development: {
    DB_DNS: "https://api-dev.web.com",
  },

  production: {
    DB_DNS: "https://api.web.com",
  },
};

const nodeEnv = process.env.REACT_APP_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

assertEnv(nodeEnv);

export default config[nodeEnv];
```

Note that this solution makes explicit the error that would have been thrown by your application had you simply type-cast an incorrect runtime value, giving you much more control and certainty over the flow. That said, you'll still have to make sure to *do* something with that error if/when it is thrown.