# What are generic constraints in typescript?

Tags: typescript

extract.ts

```js
function extract1<S>(source: S, key: keyof S) {
  return source[key]
}
function extract2<S, K extends keyof S>(source: S, key: K) {
  return source[key]
}
```

main.ts

```js
const source = {foo: 1, bar: '2'}

// Type is deduced as `string | number`
const result1 = extract1(source, 'foo')

// Type is deduced as `number`
const result2 = extract2(source, 'foo')
```

What's the difference between `extract1` and `extract2`, why the return type of extract2 can be deduced accurately, but not extract1?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think this question was already asked. Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099153/3977134 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between of "K extends keyof T" vs. directly using "keyof T"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099089/difference-between-of-k-extends-keyof-t-vs-directly-using-keyof-t)

Comment: That's exactly what i want! Thank you!